# You're Here Right Now!

Tags: riddle, word

More Riley Riddles coming your way!

> > **RIDDLE :**
>
> My prefix is whole
>
> I mean, *literally* whole
>
> My infix has something to do with money
>
> It comes as a %
>
> My suffix can help many people
>
> But it can also be for fun
>
> And you are all here right now!
>
> > > **NOTES :**
> >
> > The last line is about the whole word
> >
> > Will add more hints in the future

Super Small Hint :

> Perhaps the answer is very near to you?

What am I?

Comment: You've clued the prefix, infix, and suffix, but what about a clue for the whole word? The best riddles have self-confirming answers, i.e. when you find the right word, everything fits together and matches neatly.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah yes, I forgot about that. Haven't made a riley riddle in a while XD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my take on this

> Internet

My prefix is whole

> Integer (Int) is a whole number

My infix has something to do with money

> TER (Total Expense Ratio) is a financial indicator used in measuring fund performance

It comes as a %

> It is a percentage indicator of Total Fund Costs/Total Fund Assets, typically well below 100% before it goes bust :p

My suffix can help many people

> Nets are a means of living for fishermen

But it can also be fun

> Some people fish for leisure with a **net**. Or as per TS. a net is often used in ball games.

And you are all here right now!

> Well the Internet is the _net_work via which we got on this site

Lets see if this works for this riddle

Comment: Indeed, it is the correct answer. Can you answer some extra parts like line 4 and also the hint :D

Comment: Opps, didnt notice the additional lines. Must have left the browser on too long prior to answering :p

Comment: It's OK. Well, I'll accept your answer tomorrow :D

Comment: BTW, what I meant about the suffix being fun is that it can be used in a basketball game as a net

Answer (score 17):

Well of course, you're

> stackexchange.com

My prefix is whole

> stack can refer to an entire collection of objects (esp. in programming)

My infix has something to do with money

> Exchange as in stock exchange

My suffix can help many people

> com stands for company which helps people through either the company you keep or by selling goods

But it can also be fun

> this site is pretty fun (this one especially). Plus it fits the title "You're Here Right Now!"

Comment: Very good answer but not the intended one :D

Comment: I might give this a $+50$ rep bounty :P